# How can I addHeaderView to a PullToRefresh and the header won't be pull down?

Tags: android, pull-to-refresh

I have used the PullToRefresh and added a header view (an ad Viewpager),all work fine including refresh data. But when pull down to refresh, the added header view will be pull down too. I dont want the added header view be pulled when refresh data,because it only shows the ad. Can it be done that the header view won't move when I pull down ?
Here is my code.

```
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragement_home, null);
    //scroll view, including ad infos
    mPullRefreshListView = new PullToRefreshListView(mContext);
    mPullRefreshListView.setOnRefreshListener(new PullToRefreshBase.OnRefreshListener<ListView>() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh(PullToRefreshBase<ListView> refreshView) {
            String label = DateUtils.formatDateTime(mContext, System.currentTimeMillis(),
                    DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_ALL);

            // Update the LastUpdatedLabel
            refreshView.getLoadingLayoutProxy().setLastUpdatedLabel(label);

            // Do work to refresh the list here.
            times++;
            if (getHomeListTask != null) {
                getHomeListTask.cancel(true);
            }
            getHomeListTask = new GetHomeListTask();
            getHomeListTask.execute();
        }
    });
    lv = mPullRefreshListView.getRefreshableView();
    lv.addHeaderView(view);

    homeListAdapter = new HomeListAdapter(mContext);//my adapter
    lv.setAdapter(homeListAdapter);
```

When pull down , view(R.layout.fragement_home) will be pulled down, that is not I want.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a headerview to the listview, add the header view before the listview in its parent ViewGroup

```
    //lv.addHeaderView(view);
    ViewGroup parent = ((ViewGroup)lv.getParent());
    for (int index = 0; index < parent.getChildCount(); index++) {
        View child = parent.getChildAt(index);
        if (child == lv){
           int insertIndex = Math.max(0, (index-1));
            parent.addView(view, insertIndex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you ! But doesn't solve problem. The added view will only be show with the LastUpdatedLabel.   And I tried mPullRefreshListView.addView(view, 0);  there be an error: addView(View, int, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView